# Graphql null pointer exception even though it is not null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to create a player using createPlayer mutation. I enter the parameters for playerDTO but I get a null pointer exception

```
Cannot invoke "com.example.basketballteam.dto.PlayerDTO.getName()" because "playerdto" is null
```

Here is my mutation :

```
input PlayerDTO{
    name:String!,
    lastName:String!,
    position:Position!
}
type Mutation{
    createPlayer(plyr: PlayerDTO):Player
    deletePlayer(id: ID):Boolean
    addPlayerToTeam(id:ID,tid:ID):Player
}
```

here is my controller

```
  @MutationMapping
    public Player createPlayer(@Argument PlayerDTO playerdto){
        return playerRepository.save(playerMapper.ToEntity(playerdto));
    }
```

and this is my mapper :

```
  public Player ToEntity(PlayerDTO playerdto){
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setName(playerdto.getName());
        player.setLastName(playerdto.getLastName());
        player.setPosition(playerdto.getPosition());

        return player;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name in the graphql schema (type Mutation) must be the same as your data transfer object parameter in your controller

```
input PlayerDTO{
    name:String!,
    lastName:String!,
    position:Position!
}

type Mutation{
    createPlayer(player: PlayerDTO):Player
    deletePlayer(id: ID):Boolean
    addPlayerToTeam(id:ID,tid:ID):Player
}
```

With this controller it should work

```
  @MutationMapping
  public Player createPlayer(@Argument PlayerDTO player){
    return playerRepository.save(playerMapper.ToEntity(player));
  }
```